# What is the general cut-off date for reviewed themes in the WordPress.org repository?

Tags: themes, wordpress.org, repository, theme-review

I know that the theme review team has been active for about one year now. Thanks to their hard work and diligence, the themes in the repo are *much* better now than ever before. However, I have noticed that there are still older themes in the repo that, at first glance, probably would not pass the review if submitted or updated today. Is there a date that anyone can point to where we might want to be wary of any themes that were last updated before then?
On a related note, is there a plan to possibly phase out some of these themes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything updated since late 2010 or so should be pretty reliable. The Guidelines have been pretty much stable since fall 2010 or so.

As for existing Themes in the repository: I think most of the Theme Review Team would like to see some policy implemented in which obsolete Themes could be suspended; however, that decision is above our pay grade. For the time being: any Theme already in the repository, regardless of when it was approved, will remain active/available.

We *have* removed some older Themes, if they were found to have a security exploit, malicious code, non-GPL-compatible license, or spammy links.